# Package exposed via two dependency chains

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, protocol-buffers, osgi-bundle, fuseesb

We have been working in jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084 with camel version 2.15.1.
I need use camel-protobuf 2.15.1 (dependency to protobuf-java 2.6.1) in the route to transform messages. Meanwhile, the proto messages are compiled with protobuf-java 3.0.

The bundle manifest includes:

```
Import-Package: org.apache.camel.dataformat.protobuf;version=" 2.15.0.3", com.google.protobuf;version="[3.0.0,3.1.0)"......
```

In this case, I get the following error message:

```
Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource esb-route [esb-route/4.0.0] because it is exposed to package 'com.google.protobuf' from resources com.google.protobuf [com.google.protobuf/3.0.0] and com.google.protobuf [com.google.protobuf/2.6.1] via two dependency chains.
Chain 1:
  esb-route [esb-route/4.0.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.protobuf)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=3.1.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.google.protobuf
  com.google.protobuf [com.google.protobuf/3.0.0]
Chain 2:
  esb-route [esb-route/4.0.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.dataformat.protobuf)(version>=2.15.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.dataformat.protobuf; uses:=com.google.protobuf
  org.apache.camel.camel-protobuf [org.apache.camel.camel-protobuf/2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.protobuf)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.google.protobuf
  com.google.protobuf [com.google.protobuf/2.6.1]
```

How can I configure my bundle so that the imported camel-protobuf doesn't use the protobuf-java 2.6.0 but 3.0?

Comment: You cannot do this. You would need to upgrade Camel to a version that support protobuf 3.x

Comment: The exception to the rule in OSGi about being able to use the multiple versions of the same package is that you can't do it _within the same bundle_.  Are you able to compile your messages using protobuf 2.6?